# Segfault at "write () ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84"

Tags: gdb, exploit

I'm solving a binary exploitation challenge using ROP. My exploit code works in theory, but it the program crashes with a SIGSEGV. Here's a exact message in `gdb`:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb6f355bc in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
84  ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
```

I've tried making sense of the `disas` output. Here's that as well:

```
(gdb) disas
Dump of assembler code for function write:
   0xb6f355b0 <+0>: ldr r12, [pc, #96]  ; 0xb6f35618
   0xb6f355b4 <+4>: ldr r12, [pc, r12]
   0xb6f355b8 <+8>: teq r12, #0
=> 0xb6f355bc <+12>:    push    {r7}        ; (str r7, [sp, #-4]!)
   0xb6f355c0 <+16>:    bne 0xb6f355dc <write+44>
   0xb6f355c4 <+20>:    mov r7, #4
   0xb6f355c8 <+24>:    svc 0x00000000
   0xb6f355cc <+28>:    pop {r7}        ; (ldr r7, [sp], #4)
   0xb6f355d0 <+32>:    cmn r0, #4096   ; 0x1000
   0xb6f355d4 <+36>:    bxcc    lr
   0xb6f355d8 <+40>:    b   0xb6e8a7d0 <__syscall_error>
   0xb6f355dc <+44>:    push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, lr}
   0xb6f355e0 <+48>:    bl  0xb6f52758 <__libc_enable_asynccancel>
   0xb6f355e4 <+52>:    mov r12, r0
   0xb6f355e8 <+56>:    pop {r0, r1, r2, r3}
   0xb6f355ec <+60>:    mov r7, #4
   0xb6f355f0 <+64>:    svc 0x00000000
   0xb6f355f4 <+68>:    mov r7, r0
   0xb6f355f8 <+72>:    mov r0, r12
   0xb6f355fc <+76>:    bl  0xb6f52810 <__libc_disable_asynccancel>
   0xb6f35600 <+80>:    mov r0, r7
   0xb6f35604 <+84>:    pop {lr}        ; (ldr lr, [sp], #4)
   0xb6f35608 <+88>:    pop {r7}        ; (ldr r7, [sp], #4)
   0xb6f3560c <+92>:    cmn r0, #4096   ; 0x1000
   0xb6f35610 <+96>:    bxcc    lr
   0xb6f35614 <+100>:   b   0xb6e8a7d0 <__syscall_error>
End of assembler dump.
```

From what I can tell, `r7` is holding some bad address. So here's `info reg`:

```
(gdb) info reg
r0             0x10790  67472
r1             0x2  2
r2             0x1078e  67470
r3             0xe59f3014   3852414996
r4             0x1078e  67470
r5             0x2  2
r6             0x1042c  66604
r7             0x0  0
r8             0x0  0
r9             0x0  0
r10            0xb6ffd000   3070218240
r11            0xe1a00000   3785359360
r12            0x0  0
sp             0x106fc  0x106fc <write_anywhere+16>
lr             0xb6edbf4c   -1225932980
pc             0xb6f355bc   0xb6f355bc <write+12>
cpsr           0x60000010   1610612752
```

For what it's worth, the architecture is ARM 32-bit, OS is Debian Stretch (Raspbian), running via QEMU.

Output of `backtrace`:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb6f355bc in write () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
#1  0xb6edbf4c in _IO_new_file_write (f=0x1042c <_start>, data=0x2, n=0)
    at fileops.c:1271
#2  0xe28bd000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Execution flows into  `_IO_new_file_write`, which calls `write`, which in turn segfaults. Here's the code:

```
Dump of assembler code for function _IO_new_file_write:
   0xb6edbf28 <+0>: push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, lr}
   0xb6edbf2c <+4>: subs    r8, r2, #0
   0xb6edbf30 <+8>: mov r6, r0
   0xb6edbf34 <+12>:    ble 0xb6edbfd8 <_IO_new_file_write+176>
   0xb6edbf38 <+16>:    mov r5, r1
   0xb6edbf3c <+20>:    mov r4, r8
   0xb6edbf40 <+24>:    mov r9, #4
   0xb6edbf44 <+28>:    b   0xb6edbf64 <_IO_new_file_write+60>
=> 0xb6edbf48 <+32>:    bl  0xb6f355b0 <write>
   0xb6edbf4c <+36>:    cmp r0, #0
   0xb6edbf50 <+40>:    blt 0xb6edbfa0 <_IO_new_file_write+120>
   0xb6edbf54 <+44>:    sub r4, r4, r0
   0xb6edbf58 <+48>:    cmp r4, #0
   0xb6edbf5c <+52>:    add r5, r5, r0
... snip ...
```

Comment: This is **operating-system** specific. What OS are you running? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56679149/edit) your question to improve it (otherwise it is unclear) by tagging it appropriately. Read [Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) and the [x86-64 ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI) and the [ARM ABI](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.subset.swdev.abi/index.html)

Comment: Read also [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and http://norvig.com/21-days.html

Comment: Study also the source code of your [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library), perhaps [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html) or [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/). It contains the code of [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) and of other [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). That code is mostly wrapping the genuine system call and managing [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

Comment: Notice also that StackOverflow is *not* a *debug-my-code* or *do-my-homework* site

Comment: I have mentioned the OS already, you probably missed it. It's Debian Stretch, for ARM 32. I'm not asking you to debug my code, I'm just curious as to what might be the reason for the segfault.

Comment: The push could be failing because the stack pointer is pointing to an address in the text segment, which is not normally writable. We could probably help more if we could see a stack backtrace and disassembly of the instructions in the top few frames.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I've updated the question with the `backtrace` output.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar issue on ARM. Not sure if this solves the problem, but there seems to be a related mosquitto bug not handling SIGPIPE signals correctly: https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/issues/530